# php losing value of variables

Tags: php, mysql

Hi this is my problem: i'm posting a value from a html form into a php page and i'm reading it in this way

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
?>
```

And everything is right. Anyway i needed to change my code with a `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` and when i try to execute an insertion query inside this if statement the $id is empty. This is the code:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
echo $id ; // this prints the right value

if(isset($_POST['submit_2']))  {
    $user = "cardatabase";
    $password = "";
    $host = "";
    $database = "my_cardatabase";
    $connessione = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

    @mysql_select_db($database, $connessione) or die( "Unable to select database");
    echo $id ; // this prints nothing
    $query = "INSERT INTO myTab (Client) VALUES ('".$id."')";
    mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close();
```

Note i know the query is right executed because i have some other auto_increment attributes that are created in my db.
I've also tried to declare $id as global variable in this ways

```
global $id;
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

but still inside the "if" it empty
and

```
$GLOBALS['id'] = $_REQUEST['id'];
if(...){
$query = "INSERT INTO myTab (Client) VALUES ('".$GLOBALS['id']."')";
}
```

but doesn't work too.

EDIT: 
html form

```
<form id="myForm" action="myPage.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $id?>">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go" id="fbutton" /> <br /> 
</form>
```

**EDIT 2:**

to answer your questions.
This form is in my page1.html
THEN in my .php i have another html form and this is the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` for, not for the one posted above (that is the one containing the $id value)
My problem is that the value i got from the first form is lost inside the if statement that CONTROLs the second form.

**EDIT 3:**
second form in this php page

```
<form action="myPage.php" method="post">    
<label for="name">Model :</label><input type="text" name="model" /> <br /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit_2" value="Go" /> <br />
</form>
```

**WorkdFlow**

Page 1: Login form - get value of id and pass to page 2

Page 2: get id value and store in $id, there's a button (example "insertion to db") that leads to Page 3, create a form to pass $id (as hidden input) to page 3

Page 3: create a new form to let user insert some kind of data in the DB and submit. Here i need to store too the value of $id i got in Page 2 to be inserted in the DB with the values i got from this last form

Comment: you can use session for this .....

Comment: something like :
`session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['id']=$_REQUEST['id'];` ??

Comment: can you show your html form submit ??

Comment: sure i'll edit in a second

Comment: I don't see why you would need session for this unless the `$id` is being used in another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your if  statment passed the condition and the id dont show ,

try change your if to this

```
  if(isset($_POST['Submit']))  {
```

note the BIG `S` not `s` in submit , becareful from sensitive cases in names.

your id you said you have echoed it notmally but better why is to echo it inside the value like that:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ; ?>">
```

EDIT:

to prevent reading from both forms try changing one of the name of the button submit

like that

```
      <input type="submit" name="second_Submit" value="Go" id="fbutton" />
```

and then use this if statment:

```
    if(isset($_POST['second_Submit']))  {
```

**EDIT2:**

page1:

make

```
 session_start(); //------put this in very top of page.
  $_SESSION['myid'] = $id ;
```

page3:

retrive it like that

```
   session_start(); //------put this in very top of page.
  echo $_SESSION['myid'] ;
```

you dont need to pass this id in page2.

your query will be

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO myTab (Client) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['myid']."')";
```

Comment: This is not the problem, i mean maybe i was not clear i'll edit my first post

Comment: ok i'll try but actually they should already be different as one is Submit and the other submit (s & S), anyway i'll try

Comment: not working ;( the fact is that as soon as the html page loads if i `echo $id;` the right value is printed! but when should be inserted in the query it's blank

Comment: changed the name of the form as you said too.

Comment: why dont you use value in your input of second form like that `<input type="text" name="model"  value ="" />`

Comment: actually i don't know :) i just copied&pasted the form i used in the very fist page where i got the $id from a text input, that's why in the second form (first i pasted above) it's passed as "hidden". Anyway the other one worked perfectly without "value", should i add it?could this be the problem?

Comment: actually i didnt understand what are form are your submitting and from where you get id ?

Comment: Page1 -> insert id for kind of login ....
Page2 -> many options (example insert something on DB)
if the user decide to insert something click a button and go to
... Page3 -> here a form need to be completed to insert the values BUT i need to insert the id (it's innoDB need foreign key). So from Page1 i get the value of ID, i store it in a php variable in page2 and try to pass to page3

Comment: ahha  why dont you use session is better and safer ?? and then you can use this id what page ever you want. wait i will edit my answer.

Comment: i created a better workflow in my first post anyway ok i'll wait your answer :)

Comment: ok seems very simple :) very top of page meaning just after <?php ??

Comment: Thanks for your time! just one last question: when insert the value in the db what's the correct syntax? `'".echo $_SESSION['myid']."'` ?

Comment: insert it like that `$_SESSION['myid']` without the echo , i used echo just to show you . this session is like other variables .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add echo

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing if condition as below.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))  {
```

and `echo $id` in hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

As per the example pasted in your question you forget to use semicolon in `echo $id  // this prints nothing` statement. I hope you are using it correctly in your code.

Comment: Yes. I mean to say you are using it `echo $id;`

Comment: oh yes i just wrote that echoes on the fly to tell you the scope of the variable